# How to use jsx in preact via cdn?

Tags: preact

got this code from preact's site, and try to make it work without babel building process, but failed, anybody knows if this is possible? Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/e281k4wz/117/

```
'use strict';

const { Component, h, render } = window.preact;

render((
    <div id="foo">
        <span>Hello, world!</span>
        <button onClick={ e => alert("hi!") }>Click Me</button>
    </div>
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to include babel before your jsx code and use the script as type="text/babel" see the following example with react

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="app-content">
          <h1>Hello from React</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is about Preact, not React.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the JSX into the JavaScript as it's a invalid syntax. 
For running the preact into the client you have to either transpile the jsx code into valid javascript or use the helper method (Component , h , render) provided by preact.

HTML

```
<h1>Render by Preact client library using h and render function</h1>
<div id="preact">

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var Component = window.preact.Component, 
    h = window.preact.h, 
    render = window.preact.render;

var PreactApp = function (props){
  return h('h1',
  {className: ''},
  'Hello from Preact world!');
}

render(PreactApp(),document.getElementById("preact"));
```

Here in JS if you see h ( converting jsx to vdom ) and render (converting vdom to html ) function actually do the magic. Read more about from the official documentation - https://preactjs.com/guide/api-reference

Working example - https://jsfiddle.net/97125m3z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Technically it *is* possible by using the HTM package, as long as you're targeting recent browsers that understand template strings. See https://github.com/developit/htm for details.

However, this will render slower than simply creating the components using h() as it is a whole heap of string parsing. It also makes it difficult to use syntax highlighting in your IDE, which makes debugging frustrating.

I used HTM when I was first getting used to using Preact without a build step, but very quickly replaced it with manually creating the components and eliminated the JSX.

You get a better understanding of how everything fits together if you don't use the JSX abstraction. Babel compiles it down into createElement calls anyway.